# Thinktecture.IdentityManager is unselected in nuget. Is still for use?

Tags: thinktecture, identity-management

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Thinktecture.IdentityManager/

> The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package
>   is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore.

Why is unselected? Is it no more in use? How can I now use IdentityManager with Thinktecture Identityserver3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that was a beta3 version that has been unlisted in favour of beta 5-4:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityManager/1.0.0-beta5-4

I too will have to update...
Not sure why they removed 'Thinktecture' from the package name (now it is just IdentityManager)